# Make wordpress plugin that will allow client to enter text in backend that will show in a div i created on frontend

Tags: wordpress, plugins

Make wordpress plugin that will allow client to enter text in backend that will show in a div i created on frontend. This is pretty much the problem and i have no idea where to start. When I say backend the client has access to the backend via shop manager role but i need a plugin i can give access to so it allows the changes

Comment: What have you tried? Can you add some code?